# First page of UIPageViewController showing black screen and not loading content

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that is working to flip through pages and all of the pages load properly except for the first page it stays black and also the loading icon does not disappear. Here is what my method looks like for setting the first view of the pageviewcontroller (it is a callback to a function that grabs info from a backend)

```
self.card.images = cardImagesArray
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
self.cardImages = cardImagesArray
let startingViewController: UIViewController = getItemController(0)!
let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]
pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Did you instantiate your starting view controller in your `getItemController` method? For example `let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardId") as! UIViewController`

Comment: I actually fixed this a while ago but don't know what I did... If you submit an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Cool. Hopefully the solution I offered is what you ended up doing for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you instantiate your starting view controller in your `getItemController` method?

For example

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardId") as! UIViewController
```

Answer (score 5):

For those (like me) who have the same problem, have been looking for the last few hours and still couldn't figure out what was wrong, here is the stupid mistake I had made that created this problem: it turned out that my viewController was an instance of UIPageViewController instead of UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks you @JulienSpronck
Thats saved my day actually, what a stupid mistake really!

Comment: Lol. me too. Newbs need to stop converting classes into something else and just make new ones.